# jqGrid server response - different format, but it works. Why?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I just figured out that jqGrid demmands the server response format to be like this:

```
{ 
  "total": "xxx", 
  "page": "yyy", 
  "records": "zzz",
  "rows" : [
    {"id" :"1", "cell" :["cell11", "cell12", "cell13"]},
    {"id" :"2", "cell":["cell21", "cell22", "cell23"]},
      ...
  ]
}
```

And that I should use json reader to map the properties in case my server response properties are other than the jqGrid defaults.

But my server response is quite different from that yet the plugin works. There are no "rows" or "page" properties in our JSON. And the total records are displayed properly. My server response example:

```
[
    {"id":1,"price":3.99,"title":"Foo"},
    {"id":2,"price":3.99,"title":"Bar"},
    ...
]
```

How come?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's absolutely correct question! The first format of input data is the input format which support the  oldest versions of jqGrid. To be able to read the second format (array of items) one have to use tricky and early not good known `jsonReader` feature of jqGrid where the properties of `jsonReader` will be defined as *functions*. The following `jsonReader` could be used

```js
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    root: function (obj) { return obj; },
    page: function () { return 1; },
    total: function () { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
}
```

Later after introduction `loadonce: true` feature the usage of the second input format (array of items with named properties) become more usual. The first format of data means **server side** paging, sorting and filtering/searching of data. The server should return *only one page of data* and inform jqGrid about the total number of pages using `total` parameter. In case of usage `loadonce: true` the server have to return **all data at once**. If the response contains `total`, `page` and `records` properties, the properties will be *ignored* and jqGrid calculate the valued based on the array of returned data.

It was a lot of errors with the usage of wrong format of input data or the usage of wrong properties of `jsonReader` which didn't corresponds the input data. I had the idea to modify the code of jqGrid to **detect and to fix** definitively wrong option of `jsonReader` based on the format of input data. I posted my suggestions as the pull request which was excepted and [merged](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/a088a05394d6598b6f6ef234e15e59efef35b18d) to the main code of jqGrid. So starting with version 4.4.5 (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:change#jqgrid_4.4.5_changes_and_fixes)) `jsonReader` can be not used in the most cases. Because of the feature both of input formats can be read by jqGrid without specifying any additional  `jsonReader` option.

Comment: Thanks for your time, @Oleg. But let me see if I got you right: it isn't possible to use server side pagination PLUS an array of items? We have thousands of records so it's reasonable to fragment the server data. Besides, we can't change the server response to a more friendly format to jqGrid.

Comment: @darksoulsong: almost everything is possible. You should just set large enough value of `total` defined as function in `jsonReader`. In the case the "Next page" button of the pager will be enabled and the user can go to the next page.